# How 3D assets are managed in real time configurators?

Tags: software, applications, graphics, 3d

We see a lot of **3D configurator web applications** on the web and even other type of **configurators in embedded systems**, such as **LED Totem displays**. From real time car configurators which every major car brand has on their website, to retail and marketing content configurators.

I always wondered, especially watching the reactivity of them, ***how the 3D rendered assets are managed in order to respond to the user behaviour and how technically speaking they are 'wired' to the application so it changes with hundreds of combinations***.

Maybe this image can explain it better:
[image]

Imagine we have this app to configure interior spaces and we want to change the colour of the wall from a colour palette feature inside our app (app in the most general meaning and not only web app):

- *In Scenario 1 there is no page or view reload and not even a refresh of the configurable image and hence we get the selected colour new wall almost immediately*
- *In Scenario 2 we do the same action but the entire page or the view is reloaded and basically an entirely new picture is loaded in the frame with that selected colour*

Of course most configurator works more or less like in the Scenario 1, but I cannot understand fully how technically we can achieve N user actions on the same 3D asset...like is that a special 3D image format or there is something else?

Comment: Lol are the two photos supposed to be different?

Comment: I think that this question is about the mechanics of a 3D render pipeline, and how aspects of an object can be parameterized, and when the scene is re-rendered after a parameter change.  Is that a reasonable summary?

Comment: You are asking whether changing something should reload the entire web page or not? This is a question of web app design and has nothing to do with 3D rendering. Of course users prefer that it doesn't reload the page, but it's technically simpler to make it reload the whole pag.e

Comment: You might get a better answer if you gave an example URL, then we could describe what had been done in that particular case by looking at the page source. An image tells us very little.